# Python list and dictionary

Tags: python

How do I access dictionaries inside a list?

```
c = [{'team':2000,'name':'a'}, {'team':3000,'name':'b'}]
values = []
for key, value in c.iteritems():
    values.append((key, value))
    print values
```

I tried accessing the list using `iteritems` but I got an error specifying `list does not have iteritems`. Then, I tried using a for loop but I still get an error specifying `list indices must be integers`.

Comment: @MoonCheesez he's using python 2.x, obviously

Comment: @DaniilRyzhkov my bad, didn't notice the `print` statement and was too fast to judge. @Bala could you include the code you used which gave you the error "list indices must be integers"?

Comment: What is your desired output on your problem?

Comment: Hey thanks I got it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your desired output is, but the problem is that `c` is a *`list()` of `dict()`s*, not a `dict()`. So if you want to loop over every key and value in each dict in the list, you need two loops:

```
In [85]: for dictionary in c:
   ....:     for key, value in dictionary.iteritems():
   ....:         values.append((key, value))
   ....:         print values
   ....:
[('name', 'a')]
[('name', 'a'), ('team', 2000)]
[('name', 'a'), ('team', 2000), ('name', 'b')]
[('name', 'a'), ('team', 2000), ('name', 'b'), ('team', 3000)]
```

You can also simplify this with a list comprehension:

```
In [96]: for dictionary in c:
    values.extend((key, value) for key, value in dictionary.iteritems())
   ....:

In [97]: values
Out[97]: [('name', 'a'), ('team', 2000), ('name', 'b'), ('team', 3000)]
```

Or, simplify it even further, as `list.extend()` can take any iterable:

```
In [112]: for dictionary in c:
    values.extend(dictionary.iteritems())
   .....:

In [113]: values
Out[113]: [('name', 'a'), ('team', 2000), ('name', 'b'), ('team', 3000)]
```

And, lastly, we can populate `values` with a single line of code using [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable), which basically "flattens" multiple iterables into a single iterable (thanks [@lvc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/779200/lvc)!):

```
In [114]: from itertools import chain

In [115]: values = list(chain.from_iterable(d.iteritems() for d in c))
```

Comment: Thanks! Love your name, btw, that's a nickname of mine ;)

Comment: You can simplify it even further by using the tuples from `iteritems` directly, rather than unpacking and repacking them - `values.extend(dictionary.iteritems())`. With itertools, you can then: `values = list(chain.from_iterable(d.iteritems() for d in c))`.

Comment: `values.extend(dictionary.iteritems())` does same effect

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
c = [{'team':2000,'name':'a'}, {'team':3000,'name':'b'}]
values = []
for row in c: 
    for key, value in row.iteritems():
         if key == 'name': 
             values.append((key, value))
print(values)

# gives this
# [('name', 'a'),  ('name', 'b'),]
```

Comment: Hi will when i run this code getting syntax error in print values.can you help me to get rid of this error.And also I want my output should print only name. eg. name:a   name:b

Comment: @Bala Did this solve it? If so, mark answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

"c" is not a dictionary therefore iteritems() will not work. Iterate through the list first to isolate the dictionaries.

```
>>> c = [{'team':2000,'name':'a'}, {'team':3000,'name':'b'}]
... for i in c:
...     for k,v in i.items():
...         print "key : "+str(k)+' *** '+ "value : "+str(v)

... key : name *** value : a
... key : team *** value : 2000
... key : name *** value : b
... key : team *** value : 3000
```